# Freeze Grid view header (odoo V12)

Tags: gridview, view, odoo, odoo-view, odoo-12

I have grid view and I want to freeze header of Grid.
Can you please guide me for this

[image]

Comment: I think using the oe_grid class extend and applying CSS for that.

Answer (score 0):

there are some free third party apps in odoo app store.
you can try [this](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/web_listview_sticky_header/).

`Thank you for you response But I am looking for Grid view.`

use css file,
then open browser's developer tool, just find header block's class_name or id, and use `position:fixed;` to stick it.

```css
.your_header{
    position:fixed;
}
```

For example: notice the style filter at lower left corner.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you response 
But I am looking for Grid view.